# Launch image gets displayed when it should not - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, launch

My app is meant to open (or if it just returns from background) only in portrait mode, even when it went to background in landscape or if it is being opened when the orientation of the device is landscape.

In iPad, whenever the orientation of the device is landscape, and I bring the app to foreground, the launch image shows up. This doesn't happen if the device orientation is portrait. (Also, I there are no launch images for landscape orientation in the project)

Also, there is a task that I do when app is going to the background. If I go to background and come back to foreground very fast, launch image shows up in both iPhone and iPad, even if the orientation is portrait.

is there any way to prevent it from showing up?

Comment: How did you add the launch image. Did you add it in plist or added from XCode project settings.

Comment: I just added the launch images with correct name (Default.png etc.) into the project, and the launch images appeared in xcode project settings. The only launch images I added are for portrait for non-retina phone, retina 4.5 inch phone, retina 4 inch phone, non-retina ipad, and retina ipad.

Answer (score 2):

Create your launch images, as of iOS 5, at least four for the iPad and three for the iPhone. Name your images as follows: (The name I am using is only an example, you can use any you want.)

```
iPadImage-Portrait.png
iPadImage-Portrait@2x.png
iPadImage-Landscape.png
iPadImage-Landscape@2x.png

iPhoneImage.png
iPhoneImage@2x.png
iPhoneImage-568h@2x.png
```

Make sure you use a distinct name for each device.

Place all of these images in the top of your app's bundle directory. Then all you do is add two keys to **YourAppName-Info.plist.**

```
Launch Image(iPad) string iPadLaunchImage
Launch Image(iPhone) string iPhoneLaunchImage
```

**Images will load properly for both devices. Note that in the Info-plist file you don't put the .png, only the base name you used for your images.**

[**Apple Docs**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)

Comment: I tried this, I put Default.png in `Launch image` and `Launch image (iPhone)` and Default-Portrait.png in `Launch image (iPad)`. But this didn't help. (Also, I have used Default@2x.png, Default-568@2x.png, Default-Portrait@2x.png. Will iOS read them by itself?)

Comment: I think this won't work, because the catch is that my app ALWAYS opens in portrait orientation because i have set it so. So whatever it does, it will never load the landscape launch image. I tried putting in the landscape launch image for iPad (not using your method) , but it didn't use that image when I opened my app from landscape orientation. It uses the portrait launch image because that is supposed to be the orientation of the app.

Comment: @neeraj +1 upvote for figuring out the issue, the above solution always worked for me will check your condition later.

Comment: It didn't solve the issue. Your answer was useful for me, so I upvoted it. But the question remains unanswered.